# Find PerformanceCounterCategory by name in system with different localization

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I have try the following code on a machine with english language setted :

```
 PerformanceCounterCategory[] categories = PerformanceCounterCategory
                                          .GetCategories()
                                          .Where ( x => x.CategoryName == "Process" )
                                          .ToArray()
```

It found an entry, but if i try the same code on a machine with italian language i am not able to find any category until i traslate it in italian (eg : process became processo).

```
PerformanceCounterCategory[] categories = PerformanceCounterCategory
                                          .GetCategories()
                                          .Where(x = > x.CategoryName == "Processo")
                                          .ToArray()
```

My problem is that i would avoid to manually transalte category name for each language i may find on customer system.

Comment: You see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804402/get-performancecounter-by-index ?

Comment: Thanks @Anton i have miss that question before, but is exactly what i looking for.