# Category does not exist. While Creating performance counter for Ram usage

Tags: memory, c++-cli, cpu-usage, performancecounter

This is the code, I am trying to run to get Memory usage.

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    PerformanceCounter^ ramCounter;
    try
    {
        Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
        ramCounter = gcnew PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        Console::WriteLine(L"Memory usgae:"+ramCounter->NextValue()+L"MB");
    }
    catch(Exception^ e)
    {
        Console::WriteLine("Error Message: "+e->Message);
        Console::WriteLine(e->StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(ramCounter!=nullptr)
        {
            ramCounter->Close();
        }
        Console::WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console::ReadLine();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting exception like

> Error Message: Category does not exist.
>
> Error Message Stack trace:
> at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String
> machine, String category, String counter)    at
> System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()    at
> System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName,
> String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean readOnly)    at
> System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName,
> String counterName)    at main(String[] args) in
> c:\users\documents\visual studio
> 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp:line
> 31

Any idea about this..

Comment: This may help you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9bde268-975f-4830-b295-8e3f60f6978f/unable-to-create-performancecounter-category-does-not-exist?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: Are you sure this is C# (as stated in the tags)? Looks more like C++ to me.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride That's a special "version" of C++ from Microsoft, c++/cli.

Answer (score 2):

This might by localization issue. On my machine your code isn't working either, because its language is German. Hence I had to create the counter with

```
 gcnew PerformanceCounter("Arbeitsspeicher", "Verfügbare MB")
```

You can find the localized name by browsing the available performance counters in the [Performance Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590344(v=ws.10).aspx).

There also is a way to retrieve the counter data in a language-independent way. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581859/retrieve-performance-counter-value-in-a-language-independent-way) for details.