# missing counters IDs in typeperf on non english windows

Tags: windows, powershell, performancecounter

I am trying to get the cpu usage value as similar as possible to how task manager shows it. Checking this [Abraham Zinala](https://superuser.com/questions/1741387/task-manger-vs-performance-monitor-cpu-usage-why-are-they-so-different#comment2698180_1741387) comment, This counter `\Processor Information(*)\% Processor Utility` matches pretty close to the task manager report.

However, my Windows 11 is in Spanish so I had to find out the ID of the counters in order not to have problems wherever this command is executed regardless of the system language.

I get the both IDs Checking the Perflib register [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5609676/1168021)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009
2454
Processor Information
2508
% Processor Utility
```

Asking by ID for this counter t responds that the counters are not valid.

```
typeperf "\2454(*)\2508" 
Error: contadores no válidos.
```

However, I can get the value perfectly if I request it with the Spanish name equivalent.

```
typeperf "\Información del procesador(*)\% de utilidad del procesador"
"12/08/2023 21:19:27.006","4.264393","0.043666","22.416960","0.039292","21.000396"
```

Checking `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\CurrentLanguage` I realize there are only ~2000 of the counters translated, vs 6000 in the english registry. Processor Information & Processor Utility are not there

I have done some more random tests with other counters, and the conclusion I draw is that I can only get the counters by ID that already exist in CurrentLanguage rather than in 009 (English).
As example, it's works perfectly with typeperf `"\238(*)\6"` that it's equivalent to `typeperf "\Procesador(*)\% de tiempo de procesador"` and both are in CurrentLanguage  register

Note: I have found out the Processor Information(*)% Processor Utility value in Spanish using `typeperf -q` and looking for a near translation meaning

```
\Información del procesador(*)\Marcas de límite de rendimiento
\Información del procesador(*)\% de límite de rendimiento
\Información del procesador(*)\% de utilidad privilegiada
\Información del procesador(*)\% de utilidad del procesador
\Información del procesador(*)\% de rendimiento del procesador
```